# Store Node.js IM App conversations in MongoDB properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io, chat

I'm Developing (yet another) Node,js + Express + Socket.IO Facebook/like Instant Messaging app.

The server-side is mostly complete, but I was looking for a proper way to store and retrieve conversations and I thought I could give MongoDB a try.

I've never worked before with noSQL databases before, so I would like some suggestions on how to deal, mainly, with the writing the proper way.

I was thinking in creating entries containing the user chatting and the chatlines with a timestamp, something simple.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though this does not exactly address the app you are looking to build, 10gen (to company that supports mongodb) has released a video of a presentation walking through the creation of an IRC chat server.  This is a very long and very extensive presentation and should cover most of the material that will be relevant for you in building your app.  Definitely seems to me like the best resource for you to get started with.

http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongonyc-2012-building-mongodb-power-chat-server

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot... I''ll check it out :D